# no. of regions a plane is divided into by $n$ lines in general position

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

My notes state **the Counting process for knowing no. of regions a plane is divided into by $n$ lines in** *general position*   :=

> Let $h_1(n)=$ No. of parts a line is divided by $n$ distinct points=$n+1$
>
> $h_2(n)=$ No. of regions a plane is divided into by $n$ lines in **general position**(*i.e. no two of them are parallel and no three of them are concurrent).*

[image]

> To find  $h_2(n)$ we proceed as follows:
>
> Suppose the plane has already been divided into  parts by $n$ straight lines in general positions;let these lines be $L_1,L_2,\ldots,L_n$.
>   Let $L_{n+1}$ be $(n+1)^{\text{th}}$ line which is in general position with $L_1,\ldots L_n$.
>
> Let $P_i=L_i\cap L_{n+1}$ ,where $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ and $P_i$'$s$ are all distinct .We have $P_1,P_2\ldots P_n$  $n$ distinct points lying on $L_{n+1}$ .These points divided $L_{n+1}$ in $h_1(n)$ parts ,with each part lying exactly in one of the regions determined by $n$ lines and it divides that region into $2$ parts .
>
> $\therefore$ we obtain :
>
> $h_2(n+1)=h_2(n)+h_1(n)$ or $h_2(n+1)-h_2(n)=h_1(n)$
>
> $\implies \triangle h_2(n)=h_1(n)$
>
> $\implies  h_2(n)=\triangle^{-1} h_1(n)$
>
> $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=\triangle^{-1} \Big(\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\Big)$
>
> $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~= \Big(\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+c\Big)$
>
> Now, $h_2(1)=n$ .Also $h_2(1)=\binom{1}{1}+\binom{1}{2}+c$=$2=0+1+c$$\implies c=1=\binom{n}{0}$
>
> $\therefore h_2(n)=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}$.

I can't understand this method as I missed my class and now I'm $\mathbf STUCK$ because I've my exam day after.Please if anyone can help me understanding logic behind this .......

Comment: You have a misprint: $h_2(n+1)=h_2(n)=h_1(n)$ should be $h_2(n+1)=h_2(n)+h_1(n)$.

Comment: @TonyK sorry for it i'll edit the mistake...

Comment: There are two parts to this proof: 1. Show that $h_2(n+1) = h_2(n)+h_1(n)$ (and hence that $h_2(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n(i+1)$); and 2. Show that $h(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n(i+1) = \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: @TonyK the thing I can't understand is how did we reach $h_2(n+1)=h_2(n)+h_1(n)$...

Comment: The new line $L_{n+1}$ crosses each of the $n$ existing lines exactly once, so it gets divided into $h_1(n)$ segments. Each of the $h_1(n)$ segments of the new line divides one of the existing regions into two.

Comment: Slight error in my second comment:  $h(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n(i+1)$ should be $h(n)=1+\sum_{i=1}^n i$.